# Implementing a custom staggeredgridlayoutmanager with variable spancount

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I need to implement a custom `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` that works the same way as https://github.com/riontech-xten/StaggeredTextGridView/blob/master/README.md, where the number of items on a row depends on the width of the objects i.e in this case `Strings`, and if there's one item left on the list it'll fill the entire space remaining.

[image: Number of items depends on width of the content]

The implementation above extends a `ScrollView` but i require one that works with a `RecyclerView`. The limitation of the above library is that it requires one to use a `String` as the object type with no provision to use a custom object, it also has no provision for an `ItemClickListener`.

How can i achieve this the above effect with a `RecyclerView` layout manager?

Comment: are you able to achieve the same?

Comment: @malavshah yes, but i found a nifty class called `FlowLayout` that extends a `ViewGroup` that achieves the same function.